# Prevent AWS API Gateway from re-ordering URL parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to port an existing API to AWS API Gateway.

I've got everything working, in that using the 'test' GUI for each of my endpoints successfully hits my configured EC2 instances.

I used the swagger import facility to automatically map all possible endpoints and their associated URL parameters.

What I've noticed is that when the request hits my API (EC2 instance) the URL has been transformed slightly. The URL parameter order has changed.

Regardless of the parameter order that I paste into the test GUI, the order of the parameters when they hit my API has been changed to the order that they are specified within the 'Method Request' GUI screen.

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is there a reason you require a specific order of your parameters?

Comment: It's a legacy requirement of the API that I'm porting over. I could modify the source code to remove this dependency but it would be easier to have AWS not transform the URL params.

Comment: Have you tried using the new "http proxy" feature? This may simplify your definition and work around this issue: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html

Comment: Had it confirmed by AWS support that there is no way to prevent this happening.

Comment: is there really no chance to avoid this behaviour? we use goodrx api and they require some specific order of query params http://www.goodrx.com/developer/documentation
With this "feature" we have no way of using this api gateway

Comment: See my answer for clarification

Comment: I’ve been banging my head on this. In my case I’m developing some mock APIs where I’m getting a hash based on attributes of the request (including the path and query string. So API gateway re-ordering these is breaking my hash alg. To work around I’m having to generate hashes based on every permutation. Ideally there is some context property that gives me the querystring as it was received, un-sorted. FWIW, this is using dotnet core and a single proxy method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this using a lambda 'custom authoriser'

I was trying to use a Lambda function as a custom authoriser which then proxies through to our HTTP API. The only data available to the custom authoriser is the 'Token' in the header (can be named anything you want - setup via API Gateway GUI). You can of course populate this with whatever values you want and one suggestion was to put the param order in this header and then perform some logic at this lambda level, however that meant modifying our API callers which wasn't desirable.

You do have access to the 'transformed' URL (e.g. 'https://df64sxl1.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod/myEndpoint) but this isn't very useful.

If you are able to utilise lambda integration (instead of custom authorisation) you might be able to achieve what you by using [payload-template mappings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) as these provide a way of accessing the raw request.